# SUSY: No-Go theorems?

Tags: symmetry, supersymmetry, poincare-symmetry

According to the [Coleman-Mandula theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem), there is no trivial unification or the Poincaré symmetry and the internal gauge symmetries. However, if we give up the commutator bounds, and we allow for fermionic generators (anticommutators), SUSY rises. My question is very simple:

1. is there some NON-SUSY non trivial symmetry containing both, the Poincaré and internal gauge symmetries, providing the SM plus gravity (diffeomorphism) symmetry?
2. If so, why SUSY after all and why should be expect SUSY to be present even if the no-SUSY scenario could be accomplished?
3. Finally, is SUSY inevitable or are we biased by current unification trials?

Comment: 1. Yes, SM + gravity works well as an effective theory well below the Planck scale. 2. There are many reasons, including the hierarchy problem. 3. SUSY is not inevitable. However, if you believe in string theory, once you add fermions, there is always some sort of SUSY on the worldsheet, but nobody forces you to believe in strings.

Comment: it's worth recalling that there is no obstruction in theories that have arbitrary symmetry group mixing internal and spacetime symmetries as long as they are non-linearly realized, that is always spontaneously broken. Conformal symmetry is another non-trivial symmetry whose generators are not Lorentz singlets that evade the Coleman-Mandula theorem